# Built-in Method to Extract Embedded Video from Content

Tags: content, videos

Is there way to extract embedded video without using a regular expression as [seen here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/extracting-all-youtube-embeds-from-all-posts)?

I was hoping that there would be a way to get them using a WordPress function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the closest you get is in the WP-Embed class:

```
autoembed( $content );
```

It says it extracts urls which are on distinct lines (like you'd put a url in for embedding it), but it then passes it to WP_Embed::shortcode().

Not quite what you want. You could dig into WP_Embed::shortcode() to see if you can figure out how to hack together your own script, but I don't think there's anything ready-made for you :/